# Error running sp_BlitzCache (v5.2)

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzcache

I've installed sp_BlitzCache (and others) from the First Responder Kit, and I am receiving the following error:

```
EXEC sp_BlitzCache;
```

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure sp_BlitzCache, Line 3878 [Batch Start Line 0]
>
> Invalid object name '#trace_flags'.

All of the other scripts appear to be working as expected, but I am not sure if I've encountered a defect, or if it has something to do with my use and/or configuration.

Also worth noting, the procedure does return 10 results, but then fails with the above error.

I've done some searching online and through the stored procedure itself. While I am confused that the **#trace_flags** temp table does not appear to have been created like the others, I cannot find code on GitHub that seems to indicate that it ever had.. So since I imagine that it has been working for others it leads me to believe that I am assuming the wrong things and/or running it incorrectly.

- **Server:** Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition
- **Version:** 10.50.6220.0 (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Thank you in advance! Both for the assistance, and for any of you who have been involved in developing the First Responder Kit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That was fixed. Upgrade to the current version, v5.3 via [the Github repository](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/master) or [our site.](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/) (Disclaimer: I'm Brent Ozar.)

Comment: Thanks @brent-ozar - Not only for the prompt and quick resolution, but for all your devotion to the SQL community! I can't believe that I didn't check out the First Responder Kit sooner!

Comment: THE Brent Ozar??!?!?!?! :D

Comment: Like Batman, but without the black rubber nipples.