# sp_BlitzCache error

Tags: sp-blitzcache

I've downloaded and installed sp_BlitzCache on my production server but it gave me the following error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure sp_BlitzCache, Line 1850 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Invalid object name '##bou_BlitzCacheProcs'.

The production server is running SQL Server 2008 R2 and I'm using MS SSMS 2016.

Comment: Which version of Blitz have you deployed? A recent version [is buggy](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/05/first-responder-kit-re-release-hubris-titles/) and there already is a patch.

Comment: The script has already been fixed in v5.3: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/172508/124033

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brent here, one of the sp_BlitzCache contributors. You emailed us that error, and I explained that you were running an older version, or didn't highlight & install the entire script (only portions of it).

Whenever you hit an error in an open source tool or script, it's a great idea to try grabbing the latest version. Hope that helps!